# $X$ ~ $uniform(0,1)$, $f_Y (y | X=x) = I( x<y<x+1 )$ ( for $0<x<1$ )

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

$X$ ~ $uniform(0,1)$, $f_Y (y | X=x) = I( x<y<x+1 )$ ( for $0<x<1$ ). Find....

a) What is the distribution of $Y$, given $X = x$?

b) What is $f(x,y)$? Distribution of $(X,Y)$?

c) $f_Y (y) =$ ?, Distribution of $Y$?

**My attempts:**

a) Is the uniform distribution just $(x,x+1)$?

b) $f(x,y) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       1 & : 0<x<1 \,\,and \,\,x<y<x+1  \\
       0 & : else
     \end{array}
   \right.$

c) $f_Y(y) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       y & : 0<y<1  \\
       2-y &: 1<y<2 \\
       0 & : else 
     \end{array}
   \right.$

Does my work seem to be on the correct path? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > $X \sim {\cal U}(0,1), f_{Y\mid X}(y \mid X=x) = \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(x, x+1)}(y) \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1)}(x)$
> >
> > a) What is the distribution of $Y$, given $X = x$?
>
> a) Is the uniform distribution just $(x,x+1)$?

$\color{red}{\checkmark} \quad [Y\mid X=x] \sim {\cal U}(x,x+1), \forall x\in (0,1)$

> > b) What is $f(x,y)$? Distribution of $(X,Y)$?
>
> b) $f(x,y) = \left\{
>      \begin{array}{ll}
>        1 & : 0<x<1 \,\,and \,\,x<y<x+1  \\
>        0 & : else
>      \end{array}
>    \right.$

$\begin{align}\color{red}{\checkmark} \quad 
 f_{X,Y}(x, y) & = f_X(x)f_{Y\mid X}(y \mid x) 
\\ & = \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1)}(x)\cdot \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(x, x+1)}(y) \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1)}(x)
\\ & = \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1)}(x)\operatorname{\bf 1}_{(x, x+1)}(y)
\\ & = \begin{cases}1 & : x\in (0,1)\cap y\in (x, x+1) \\ 0 & : \text{elsewise}\end{cases}
\\ & = \begin{cases}1 & : y\in(0,1)\cap x\in (0,y)
  \\ 1 & : y\in(1,2)\cap x\in (y-1,1)
  \\ 0 & : \text{elsewise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}$

> > c) $f_Y (y) =$ ?, Distribution of $Y$?
>
> c) $f_Y(y) = \left\{
>      \begin{array}{ll}
>        y & : 0<y<1  \\
>        2-y &: 1<y<2 \\
>        0 & : else 
>      \end{array}
>    \right.$

$\begin{align}\color{red}{\checkmark} \quad 
f_Y(y) & = \int_{\bf X} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname{d}x
\\ & = \int_{\bf X} \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1)}(x)\operatorname{\bf 1}_{(x, x+1)}(y) \operatorname{d}x
\\ & = \int_{\bf X} \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1]}(y)\operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,y)}(x)+ \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(1, 2)}(y)\operatorname{\bf 1}_{(y-1, 1)}(x) \operatorname{d}x
\\ & = \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1]}(y)\int_{0}^y \operatorname{d}x+ \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(1, 2)}(y)\int_{y-1}^1 \operatorname{d}x
\\ & = \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(0,1]}(y)\cdot (y) + \operatorname{\bf 1}_{(1,2)}(y)\cdot(2-y)
\\ & = \begin{cases}y & : y\in (0, 1] \\ 2-y & : y\in (1,2) \\ 0 & : \text{else}\end{cases}
\end{align}$